# Customer information saves successfully on table 1, but does not save the customer product information on table 2

Tags: php

When I save a customer's information (name, address, quotation date, etc) it saves the data successfully on the table named "tbl_order", but the data for product names, price, quantities, etc, is not being saved on the table named "tbl_order_item". The strange part is that the code runs and works perfectly on my localhost (production), but when I upload the code to the actual site, it does not function properly.

NOTE: I have not cleaned up the code (refactored) yet. I will do so once it works properly.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Below is my code:

```
    <?php session_start(); ?>

<?php
  if (!isset($_SESSION['username']))
  {
    header("Location: index.php");
  }
?>

<?php
  include('./includes/database_connection_main.php');

  $statement = $connect->prepare("
    SELECT * FROM tbl_order
    ORDER BY order_id DESC
  ");

  $statement->execute();

  $all_result = $statement->fetchAll();

  $total_rows = $statement->rowCount();

  if(isset($_POST["create_invoice"]))
  {
    $order_total_before_tax = 0;
    $order_total_tax1 = 0;
    $order_total_tax = 0;
    $order_total_after_tax = 0;
    $statement = $connect->prepare("

      INSERT INTO tbl_order
        (quote_date, lead_time, good_until, order_receiver_name, company_name, address_line_1, city, state, zip_code, phone_number, email, note_1, note_2, note_3, note_4, order_total_before_tax, order_total_tax1, order_total_tax, order_total_after_tax, order_datetime)
        VALUES (:quote_date, :lead_time, :good_until, :order_receiver_name, :company_name, :address_line_1, :city, :state, :zip_code, :phone_number, :email, :note_1, :note_2, :note_3, :note_4, :order_total_before_tax, :order_total_tax1, :order_total_tax, :order_total_after_tax, :order_datetime)
    ");
    $statement->execute(
      array(
          ':quote_date'                   =>  trim($_POST["quote_date"]),
          ':lead_time'                    =>  trim($_POST["lead_time"]),
          ':good_until'                   =>  trim($_POST["good_until"]),
          ':order_receiver_name'          =>  trim($_POST["order_receiver_name"]),
          ':company_name'                 =>  trim($_POST["company_name"]),
          ':address_line_1'               =>  trim($_POST["address_line_1"]),
          ':city'                         =>  trim($_POST["city"]),
          ':state'                        =>  trim($_POST["state"]),
          ':zip_code'                     =>  trim($_POST["zip_code"]),
          ':phone_number'                 =>  trim($_POST["phone_number"]),
          ':email'                        =>  trim($_POST["email"]),
          ':note_1'                       =>  trim($_POST["note_1"]),
          ':note_2'                       =>  trim($_POST["note_2"]),
          ':note_3'                       =>  trim($_POST["note_3"]),
          ':note_4'                       =>  trim($_POST["note_4"]),
          ':order_total_before_tax'       =>  $order_total_before_tax,
          ':order_total_tax1'             =>  $order_total_tax1,
          ':order_total_tax'              =>  $order_total_tax,
          ':order_total_after_tax'        =>  $order_total_after_tax,
          ':order_datetime'               =>  date("Y-m-d")
      )
    );

      $statement = $connect->query("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()");
      $order_id = $statement->fetchColumn(); //use this to view the quote number on the pdf document

      for($count=0; $count<$_POST["total_item"]; $count++)
      {
        $order_total_before_tax = $order_total_before_tax + floatval(trim($_POST["order_item_actual_amount"][$count]));

        $order_total_tax1 = $order_total_tax1 + floatval(trim($_POST["order_item_tax1_amount"][$count]));

        $order_total_after_tax = $order_total_after_tax + floatval(trim($_POST["order_item_final_amount"][$count]));

        $statement = $connect->prepare("
          INSERT INTO tbl_order_item
          (order_id, sku, item_name, order_item_quantity, order_item_price, order_item_actual_amount, order_item_tax1_rate, order_item_tax1_amount, order_item_final_amount)
          VALUES (:order_id, :sku, :item_name, :order_item_quantity, :order_item_price, :order_item_actual_amount, :order_item_tax1_rate, :order_item_tax1_amount, :order_item_final_amount)
        ");

        $statement->execute(
          array(
            ':order_id'                   =>  $order_id,
            ':sku'                        =>  trim($_POST["sku"][$count]),
            ':item_name'                  =>  trim($_POST["item_name"][$count]),
            ':order_item_quantity'        =>  trim($_POST["order_item_quantity"][$count]),
            ':order_item_price'           =>  trim($_POST["order_item_price"][$count]),
            ':order_item_actual_amount'   =>  trim($_POST["order_item_actual_amount"][$count]),
            ':order_item_tax1_rate'       =>  trim($_POST["order_item_tax1_rate"][$count]),
            ':order_item_tax1_amount'     =>  trim($_POST["order_item_tax1_amount"][$count]),
            ':order_item_final_amount'    =>  trim($_POST["order_item_final_amount"][$count])
          )
        );
      }
      $order_total_tax = $order_total_tax1;

      $statement = $connect->prepare("
        UPDATE tbl_order
        SET order_total_before_tax = :order_total_before_tax,
        order_total_tax1 = :order_total_tax1,
        order_total_tax = :order_total_tax,
        order_total_after_tax = :order_total_after_tax
        WHERE order_id = :order_id
      ");
      $statement->execute(
        array(
          ':order_total_before_tax'     =>  $order_total_before_tax,
          ':order_total_tax1'           =>  $order_total_tax1,
          ':order_total_tax'            =>  $order_total_tax,
          ':order_total_after_tax'      =>  $order_total_after_tax,
          ':order_id'                   =>  $order_id
        )
      );
      header("location:invoice_list.php");
  }

  if(isset($_POST["update_invoice"]))
  {
    $order_total_before_tax = 0;
      $order_total_tax1 = 0;
      $order_total_tax = 0;
      $order_total_after_tax = 0;

      $order_id = $_POST["order_id"];



      $statement = $connect->prepare("
                DELETE FROM tbl_order_item WHERE order_id = :order_id
            ");
            $statement->execute(
                array(
                    ':order_id'       =>      $order_id
                )
            );

      for($count=0; $count<$_POST["total_item"]; $count++)
      {
        $order_total_before_tax = $order_total_before_tax + floatval(trim($_POST["order_item_actual_amount"][$count]));
        $order_total_tax1       = $order_total_tax1 + floatval(trim($_POST["order_item_tax1_amount"][$count]));
        $order_total_after_tax  = $order_total_after_tax + floatval(trim($_POST["order_item_final_amount"][$count]));
        $statement = $connect->prepare("
          INSERT INTO tbl_order_item
          (order_id, sku, item_name, order_item_quantity, order_item_price, order_item_actual_amount, order_item_tax1_rate, order_item_tax1_amount, order_item_final_amount)
          VALUES (:order_id, :sku, :item_name, :order_item_quantity, :order_item_price, :order_item_actual_amount, :order_item_tax1_rate, :order_item_tax1_amount, :order_item_final_amount)
        ");
        $statement->execute(
          array(
            ':order_id'                 =>  $order_id,
            ':sku'                      =>  trim($_POST["sku"][$count]),
            ':item_name'                =>  trim($_POST["item_name"][$count]),
            ':order_item_quantity'      =>  trim($_POST["order_item_quantity"][$count]),
            ':order_item_price'         =>  trim($_POST["order_item_price"][$count]),
            ':order_item_actual_amount' =>  trim($_POST["order_item_actual_amount"][$count]),
            ':order_item_tax1_rate'     =>  trim($_POST["order_item_tax1_rate"][$count]),
            ':order_item_tax1_amount'   =>  trim($_POST["order_item_tax1_amount"][$count]),
            ':order_item_final_amount'  =>  trim($_POST["order_item_final_amount"][$count])
          )
        );
        $result = $statement->fetchAll();
      }
      $order_total_tax = $order_total_tax1;

      $statement = $connect->prepare("
        UPDATE tbl_order
        SET order_no = :order_no,
        order_date = :order_date,
        order_receiver_name = :order_receiver_name,
        order_receiver_address = :order_receiver_address,
        order_total_before_tax = :order_total_before_tax,
        order_total_tax1 = :order_total_tax1,
        order_total_tax = :order_total_tax,
        order_total_after_tax = :order_total_after_tax
        WHERE order_id = :order_id
      ");

      $statement->execute(
        array(
          ':order_no'                 =>  trim($_POST["order_no"]),
          ':order_date'               =>  trim($_POST["order_date"]),
          ':order_receiver_name'      =>  trim($_POST["order_receiver_name"]),
          ':order_receiver_address'   =>  trim($_POST["order_receiver_address"]),
          ':order_total_before_tax'   =>  $order_total_before_tax,
          ':order_total_tax1'         =>  $order_total_tax1,
          ':order_total_tax'          =>  $order_total_tax,
          ':order_total_after_tax'    =>  $order_total_after_tax,
          ':order_id'                 =>  $order_id
        )
      );

      $result = $statement->fetchAll();

      header("location:invoice_list.php");
  }

  if(isset($_GET["delete"]) && isset($_GET["id"]))
  {
    $statement = $connect->prepare("DELETE FROM tbl_order WHERE order_id = :id");
    $statement->execute(
      array(
        ':id'       =>      $_GET["id"]
      )
    );
    $statement = $connect->prepare(
      "DELETE FROM tbl_order_item WHERE order_id = :id");
    $statement->execute(
      array(
        ':id'       =>      $_GET["id"]
      )
    );
    header("location:invoice_list.php");
  }

  ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"><!--search pagination and delete reference link-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script><!--search pagination and delete reference link-->

  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="container-fluid">
      <?php
      if(isset($_GET["add"]))
      {
      ?>
      <form method="post" id="create_form">
        <div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="table table-bordered">
            <tr>
              <td colspan="2" align="">
                <div><?php echo "Logged in as:" . " " . $_SESSION['username']; ?></div>
                <div align=""><li style="list-style-type: none;"><a href="invoice_list.php">Dashboard</a></li></div>
                <div align=""><li style="list-style-type: none;"><a href="./includes/logout.php">Log Out</a></li></div>
              </td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="2" align="center"><img src="images/dpb_logo.png" alt="DBP Logo" height="" width=""></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-8">

                        <b>RECEIVER (BILL TO)</b>
                        <input type="text" name="order_receiver_name" id="order_receiver_name" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="customer name" />
                        <input type="text" name="company_name" id="company_name" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="company name" />
                        <input type="text" name="address_line_1" id="address_line_1" class="form-control" placeholder="address line 1" />
                        <input type="text" name="city" id="city" class="form-control" placeholder="city" />
                        <input type="text" name="state" id="states" class="form-control" placeholder="state" />
                        <input type="text" name="zip_code" id="zip_code" class="form-control" placeholder="zip code" />
                        <input type="text" name="phone_number" id="phone_number" class="form-control" placeholder="phone number" />
                        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="email" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                      <label for=""><b>Quote Date:</b></label>
                      <input type="date" name="quote_date" id="quote_date" class="form-control input-sm" />
                      <br>
                      <label for=""><b>Lead Time:</b></label>
                      <input type="text" name="lead_time" id="lead_time" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Enter Lead Time" />
                      <br>
                      <label for=""><b>Good Until:</b></label>
                      <input type="date" name="good_until" id="good_until" class="form-control input-sm" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <br />
                  <table id="invoice-item-table" class="table table-bordered">
                    <tr>
                      <th width="1%">Items</th>
                      <th width="4%">SKU</th>
                      <th width="40%">Item Description</th>
                      <th width="1%">Quantity</th>
                      <th width="7%">Price</th>
                      <th width="1%">Subtotal</th>
                      <th width="3%" colspan="2">Tax Percentage</th>
                      <th width="3%">Row Total</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <th></th>
                      <th></th>
                      <th></th>
                      <th></th>
                      <th></th>
                      <th></th>
                      <th>Tax%</th>
                      <th>Rate</th>
                      <th></th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td><span id="sr_no">1</span></td>
                      <td><input type="text" name="sku[]" id="sku" class="form-control input-sm" /></td>
                      <td><input type="text" name="item_name[]" id="item_name1" class="form-control input-sm" /></td>
                      <td><input type="text" name="order_item_quantity[]" id="order_item_quantity1" data-srno="1" class="form-control input-sm order_item_quantity" /></td>
                      <td><input type="text" name="order_item_price[]" id="order_item_price1" data-srno="1" class="form-control input-sm number_only order_item_price" /></td>
                      <td><input type="text" name="order_item_actual_amount[]" id="order_item_actual_amount1" data-srno="1" class="form-control input-sm order_item_actual_amount" readonly /></td>
                      <td><input type="text" name="order_item_tax1_rate[]" id="order_item_tax1_rate1" data-srno="1" class="form-control input-sm number_only order_item_tax1_rate" /></td>
                      <td><input type="text" name="order_item_tax1_amount[]" id="order_item_tax1_amount1" data-srno="1" readonly class="form-control input-sm order_item_tax1_amount" /></td>
                      <td><input type="text" name="order_item_final_amount[]" id="order_item_final_amount1" data-srno="1" readonly class="form-control input-sm order_item_final_amount" /></td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                  <div align="right">
                    <button type="button" name="add_row" id="add_row" class="btn btn-success btn-xs">+</button>
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td align="right"><b>Total</td>
                <td align="right"><b><span id="final_total_amt"></span></b></td>
              </tr>


                <tr>
                  <td colspan="2">
                    <div align="center"><label for="additional_information"><b><u>Additional Information</u></b></label></div>
                    <input type="text" name="note_1" id="note_1" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Enter note 1" />
                    <input type="text" name="note_2" id="note_2" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Enter note 2" />
                    <input type="text" name="note_3" id="note_3" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Enter note 3" />
                    <input type="text" name="note_4" id="note_4" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Enter note 4" />
                  </td>


                  <td></td>
                </tr>

              <tr>
                <td colspan="2" align="center">
                  <input type="hidden" name="total_item" id="total_item" value="1" />
                  <input type="submit" name="create_invoice" id="create_invoice" class="btn btn-info" value="Save" />
                </td>
              </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
      </form>

      <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        var final_total_amt = $('#final_total_amt').text();
        var count = 1;

        $(document).on('click', '#add_row', function(){
          count++;
          $('#total_item').val(count);
          var html_code = '';
          html_code += '<tr id="row_id_'+count+'">';
          html_code += '<td><span id="sr_no">'+count+'</span></td>';

          html_code += '<td><input type="text" name="sku[]" id="sku'+count+'" class="form-control input-sm" /></td>';
          html_code += '<td><input type="text" name="item_name[]" id="item_name'+count+'" class="form-control input-sm" /></td>';

          html_code += '<td><input type="text" name="order_item_quantity[]" id="order_item_quantity'+count+'" data-srno="'+count+'" class="form-control input-sm number_only order_item_quantity" /></td>';
          html_code += '<td><input type="text" name="order_item_price[]" id="order_item_price'+count+'" data-srno="'+count+'" class="form-control input-sm number_only order_item_price" /></td>';
          html_code += '<td><input type="text" name="order_item_actual_amount[]" id="order_item_actual_amount'+count+'" data-srno="'+count+'" class="form-control input-sm order_item_actual_amount" readonly /></td>';

          html_code += '<td><input type="text" name="order_item_tax1_rate[]" id="order_item_tax1_rate'+count+'" data-srno="'+count+'" class="form-control input-sm number_only order_item_tax1_rate" /></td>';
          html_code += '<td><input type="text" name="order_item_tax1_amount[]" id="order_item_tax1_amount'+count+'" data-srno="'+count+'" readonly class="form-control input-sm order_item_tax1_amount" /></td>';

          html_code += '<td><input type="text" name="order_item_final_amount[]" id="order_item_final_amount'+count+'" data-srno="'+count+'" readonly class="form-control input-sm order_item_final_amount" /></td>';
          html_code += '<td width="1%"><button type="button" name="remove_row" id="'+count+'" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs remove_row">X</button></td>';
          html_code += '</tr>';
          $('#invoice-item-table').append(html_code);
        });

        $(document).on('click', '.remove_row', function(){
          var row_id = $(this).attr("id");
          var total_item_amount = $('#order_item_final_amount'+row_id).val();
          var final_amount = $('#final_total_amt').text();
          var result_amount = parseFloat(final_amount) - parseFloat(total_item_amount);
          $('#final_total_amt').text(result_amount);
          $('#row_id_'+row_id).remove();
          count--;
          $('#total_item').val(count);
        });

        function cal_final_total(count)
        {
          var final_item_total = 0;
          for(j=1; j<=count; j++)
          {
            var quantity = 0;
            var price = 0;
            var actual_amount = 0;
            var tax1_rate = 0;
            var tax1_amount = 0;
            var item_total = 0;
            quantity = $('#order_item_quantity'+j).val();
            if(quantity > 0)
            {
              price = $('#order_item_price'+j).val();
              if(price > 0)
              {
                actual_amount = parseFloat(quantity) * parseFloat(price);
                $('#order_item_actual_amount'+j).val(actual_amount);
                tax1_rate = $('#order_item_tax1_rate'+j).val();
                if(tax1_rate > 0)
                {
                  tax1_amount = parseFloat(actual_amount)*parseFloat(tax1_rate)/100;
                  $('#order_item_tax1_amount'+j).val(tax1_amount);
                }

                item_total = parseFloat(actual_amount) + parseFloat(tax1_amount);
                final_item_total = parseFloat(final_item_total) + parseFloat(item_total);
                $('#order_item_final_amount'+j).val(item_total);
              }
            }
          }
          $('#final_total_amt').text(final_item_total);
        }

        $(document).on('blur', '.order_item_price', function(){
          cal_final_total(count);
        });

        $(document).on('blur', '.order_item_tax1_rate', function(){
          cal_final_total(count);
        });

        $('#create_invoice').click(function(){
          if($.trim($('#order_receiver_name').val()).length == 0)
          {
            alert("Please Enter Receiver Name");
            return false;
          }

          for(var no=1; no<=count; no++)
          {

            if($.trim($('#item_name'+no).val()).length == 0)
            {
              alert("Please Enter Item Name");
              $('#item_name'+no).focus();
              return false;
            }

            if($.trim($('#order_item_quantity'+no).val()).length == 0)
            {
              alert("Please Enter Quantity");
              $('#order_item_quantity'+no).focus();
              return false;
            }

            if($.trim($('#order_item_price'+no).val()).length == 0)
            {
              alert("Please Enter Price");
              $('#order_item_price'+no).focus();
              return false;
            }

          }

          $('#create_form').submit();

        });

      });
      </script>
      <?php
      }
    ?>

<script>//check if the value that we anter on the price and quantity fields are numbers
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.number_only').keypress(function(e){
return isNumbers(e, this);
});
function isNumbers(evt, element)
{
var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
if (
(charCode != 46 || $(element).val().indexOf('.') != -1) &&      // “.” CHECK DOT, AND ONLY ONE.
(charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
return false;
return true;
}
});
</script>
```

Comment: What debugging have you done?  Have you checked that `$order_id` is populated correctly?  Have you confirmed that you are getting within the `for($count=0; $count<$_POST["total_item"]; $count++)` loop?

Comment: Hi Patrick Q,

I am pretty new with php. How would I go about checking if the $order_id is actually being populated with the last inserted id?

Comment: How could you possibly have written all this without knowing something basic like how to dump a value? Put `var_dump($order_id); exit;` after `$order_id = $statement->fetchColumn();`  The value should be the same as the auto increment value on the newest row.

Comment: Hi Patrick Q, the $order_id is being populated correctly. The value is the same as the auto increment value.

Comment: Hi Patrick Q, I also ran the var_dump() on the loop to check if $count is "counting" for the total items and it returned the count for the items. Now I am completely out of clues/ideas. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer to the issue I was having. The database for some reason requires that the $order_total_before_tax, order_total_tax1, order_total_tax, order_total_tax, order_total_after_tax fields be entered with a value from the submission form. Since sometimes the customer will not be taxed on their quotation, the tax fields are not entered, thus causing the database to not insert the information on the second table called "tbl_order_item". I will look for a work around this.